# how can I change a column identity of kentico table?

Tags: database, kentico, media-library

I'm getting  an error each time that I try to create a new media library. The error is: "Cannot insert NULL into column 'LibrarySiteId'" but I did not change this default value. Some advice, please.

Comment: Provide more information about your problem. What version are you working with? Are you doing this in the API or in the Kentico UI? Have you made any modifications lately to your code base? Have you recently done an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [API to create media library](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/media-libraries#Medialibraries-Creatingamedialibrary)? Probably SiteContext.CurrentSiteID is null. DB wise you are trying to insert new row into Media_library table and it the table has constraint (Not Null) on LibrarySiteId field.

To get all the sites information you can check db: `select SiteID, SiteName from cms_site`. Now you need to set correct siteId: you can hard-code it or get it using api:

```
int siteID;
SiteInfo siteForMediaLibrary = SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteInfo("SiteName");
if (siteForMediaLibrary != null)
{
    siteID = siteForMediaLibrary.SiteID;
}
```

...

Later when you add your library you do

`newLibrary.LibrarySiteID = siteID`;